# Distinct MAC and Key for AEAD?

Tags: mac, authenticated-encryption

I am implementing some of the algorithms in [RFC 7518](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518) and I noticed that [AES_CBC_HMAC_SHA2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#section-5.2.2.1) contains the following paragraph:

> 1. The secondary keys MAC_KEY and ENC_KEY are generated from the
>    input key K as follows.  Each of these two keys is an octet
>    string.
>
>    MAC_KEY consists of the initial MAC_KEY_LEN octets of K, in order.
>    ENC_KEY consists of the final ENC_KEY_LEN octets of K, in order.
>
>    The number of octets in the input key K MUST be the sum of
>    MAC_KEY_LEN and ENC_KEY_LEN.  The values of these parameters are
>    specified by the Authenticated Encryption algorithms in Sections
>    5.2.3 through 5.2.5.  Note that the MAC key comes before the
>    encryption key in the input key K; this is in the opposite order
>    of the algorithm names in the identifier "AES_CBC_HMAC_SHA2".

Why would the encryption key be different than the MAC key? The examples I see in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption#Approaches_to_authenticated_encryption) show that the same key is used for both.

My understanding is that because in JWE only the message is authenticated, it means that the key is available for tempering and since the MAC key and the MAC are in a known location, it should be possible to forge messages.

Am I incorrect in that assumption? Why did the RFC authors chose to split the keys instead of reusing it?

Comment: Note that SIV uses the same construct. I'm not a fan of it; it could play merry hell when trying to derive keys within a HSM, to name one issue, and the keys need then to be split up anyway. If you design an AEAD scheme having it accept a single (AES) key is certainly preferred from the view of most users. Special types of key with double the size of normal keys are hard to handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The examples I see in wikipedia show that the same key is used for
>   both.

Doing so is fine *in most constructions*, however "most" is not "all". Also the graphics could be read as "derive a key from the given input key somehow".

> Why would the encryption key be different than the MAC key?

Cryptographically speaking, it's *cleaner* to use different keys for the different primitives, as it *definitely* prevents subtle interactions due to the key-reuse and thus makes formal proofs about security claims easier.

Also there are cases where you actually *have to* use different keys for the MAC and the encryption scheme, the most well-known example being the combination of [CBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_(CBC)) and [CBC-MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CBC-MAC) which allows for modification of (nearly) the whole message on key-reuse.